# How can i calculate the progress of a file download in percentages?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
        void fileDownloadRadar(string uri, string fileName)
        {
            request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.ContentType == "")
            {
                Logger.Write("ContentType is Empty download was not fine !!!!!");
            }
            if ((response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
                response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect) &&
                response.ContentType.StartsWith("image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Logger.Write("ContentType is not empty meaning download is fine");
                using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead != 0);

                }
                FinishWebRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer3.Start();
            }
        }
```

Inside this method somehow i want to calcuate the file download progress and report it to form1 consturctor:

In form1 constructor i did:

```
fileDownloadRadar(remote_image_on_server, combinedTemp);
splash.UpdateProgressBar(
```

The UpdateProgressBar should accept int.
In the form splash i update the progressBar1 i have there.

My question is how to calculate the download progress in real time in the fileDownloadRadar and how to report it to the splash.UpdateProgressBar method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should run file download in separate thread and then use events to update progress bar.

You could check progress by calculating left bytes amount.

Here is simillar question that contains your problem solution: 
[C# download file with progress indicator and then install file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017350/c-sharp-download-file-with-progress-indicator-and-then-install-file)